# В их перелёте на Африку? При перелёте их в Африку?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

> Осень. Здесь она наполнена гомоном самых разных птиц, оседающих на
>   землях империи ненадолго, в их перелёте на Африку.

Comment: В **своём** перелете в Африку/к Африке (полёте курсом на Африку). В **их** перелёте им может помогать попутный ветер, а здесь они сами действуют (оседают).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Осень. Здесь она наполнена гомоном самых разных птиц, **оседающих на землях империи ненадолго, при перелёте в Африку.**

1) Нельзя сказать: птицы оседают при ***их*** перелете. Действие относится к птицам, поэтому правильно: птицы оседают при ***своем*** перелете. Сравнить: мы наблюдали за ***их*** перелетом (это уже наше действие).

Но местоимение ***свой*** здесь кажется лишним, лучше вообще его опустить.

2) Желательно использовать форму ***в Африку***, перелет ***на Африку*** звучит необычно. Мы можем сказать: перелет с острова на остров, перелет на родину, на континент, даже перелет на Мальдивы, но не на Африку. Птицы улетают и перелетают из Европы в Африку.